# jQuery $.extend namespacing

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you extend an object prototype with a nested namespace?

http://jsfiddle.net/2t5314nu/2/

I want to be able to call nested methods from `Obj.prototype` like `this.nested.method` and be able to access prototype properties and methods from `nested` as `this.prop`.

However, when I use jQuery `$.extend`, the `init` method from `nested` overrides the one from `Obj.prototype`. In fact, `Obj.prototype.init` is never called.

I want to avoid overriding `Obj.prototype.init` with `nested.init`. I would be fine with using something other than `$.extend`.

```
function Obj() {
  this.prop = 'val';
  this.init();
}

Obj.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    console.log('object init');
    console.log('prop in object init: ' + this.prop);
    $('#object-init').text('object init');
    this.nested.init();
    this.nested.method();
  }
};

var nested = {
  init: function() {
    console.log('nested init');
    console.log('prop in nested init: ' + this.prop);
    $('#nested-init').text('nested init');
  },
  method: function() {
    console.log('nested method');
    console.log('prop in nested method: ' + this.prop);
    $('#nested-method').text('nested method');
  }
};

$.extend(true, Obj.prototype, nested);

new Obj();
```

Comment: What behaviour do you expect to see? You've overwritten a function, so the original one is not invoked.

Comment: Instead of `this.nested.init()` try  `nested.init.call(this)`

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: the prototyped method is not invoked. Not to say that your proposal is just not correct.

Comment: @zerkms: My hope is to set the context in `nested` to be `Obj`; that seems to be the main issue I can't figure out: http://jsfiddle.net/2t5314nu/3/

Comment: @cantera: the context is resolved in runtime depending how you invoke it. In *your code* you don't invoke it.

Comment: @zerkms: Do you mean doing something like `bind(this)` when I call nested methods? Or when I do the `$.extend`?

Comment: @cantera: No I don't. I mean that in your code you **DO NOT** invoke the prototyped `init` method at all. So it's not obvious what you want to gain with **your** code (not with code someone else provided to you). So what is the "expected" result for your code? `$.extend()` just a dummy "take from here and put there" function, so it's not what causes the problem.

Comment: @zerkms: the call to `this.init` in the constructor is intended to call `Obj.prototype.init`. I want to prevent `$.extend` from overriding `Object.prototype.init` with `nested.init`.

Comment: Well, you've asked it to override it, so it did. What you want instead of overriding? Just remove `init` from `nested` and it will not override it.

Comment: Right, and I'm asking how to avoid overriding. I want to be able to call `this.init()` and `this.nested.init()` and have them both work.

Comment: @cantera: only one function can be available via `this.init`. Ayou could `apply` or `call` then. `this.nested.init.call(this)`

Comment: Have you tried passing in "false", instead of "true" in your extend method? When that is the case, I get: object init in your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

this.nested is undefined in the code you posted.  give the nested object a name when you call extend so its added to a particular spot rather than overwriting:

$.extend( true, Obj.prototype, { nested: nested })

Comment: It was not me but it makes sense to put some accompanying text so that it was *helpful* for the OP. And your explanation is actually not consistent "this.nested is undefined in the code you posted" --- is not a problem, since that code is not even running.

Comment: +1 for {nested: nested} but unfortunately the Obj.prototype properties are undefined in the nested methods: http://jsfiddle.net/2t5314nu/3/

Answer (score -1):

You may not know what `this` in JavaScript is, it's the invoking object so `this` is the object before the method:

```
peter.doSomothing();//this in doSomething is peter
peter.nested.doSomething();//this in doSomething is nested
new Person();//when new is used this is the Person instance to be created
```

You can use .call or .apply when invoking methods of nested to define the invoking object  (as already stated in the comments).

```
function Obj() {
  this.prop = 'val';
  this.init();
}

Obj.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    console.log('in Obj.prototype.init: ' + this.prop);
    nested.init.call(this);
    nested.method.call(this);
  }
};

var nested = {
  init: function() {
    console.log('nested init');
    console.log('prop in nested init: ' + this.prop);
  },
  method: function() {
    console.log('nested method');
    console.log('prop in nested method: ' + this.prop);
  }
};
var o = new Obj();
```

Or you can have an Obj instance have a Nested instance that has a reference to the Obj:

```
var Nested = function Nested(objInstance){
  this.objInstance = objInstance;
};
Nested.prototype.init = function init(){
  console.log('init in nested',this.objInstance);
  this.method();
};
Nested.prototype.method = function method(){
  console.log('method in nested',this.objInstance);
};
var Obj = function Obj(){
  this.nested = new Nested(this);
  this.prop='prop of Obj';
};
Obj.prototype.init = function init(){
  console.log('init in Obj',this);
  this.nested = new Nested(this);
};
var objInstance = new Obj();
objInstance.init();
objInstance.nested.init();
```

More on constructor functions and prototype here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941